# Does an adverb go before or after a prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adverbs, prepositional-phrases

For example:

He spoke optimistically to the people.
vs.
He spoke to the people optimistically.
vs.
He optimistically spoke to the people.
vs.
Optimistically, he spoke to the people.

Comment: I did a google search, but I could not find anything conclusive.

Comment: All of the above are correct. It would be a matter of context and style and emphasis when to use any of them.You might wish to add a comma here and there.

Comment: It's an awkward thing to google.  I'd say that they are all grammatical, and none of them leap out as being inherently preferable.

Comment: There can be a difference in meaning depending on whether the adverb precedes or follows the verb. After the verb, the optimism informs the content of speech; before the verb, it can be his motivation for speaking or his hope for results.

Answer (score 2):

> Place adverbs as close as possible to the words they are supposed to
> modify. Putting the adverb in the wrong spot can produce an awkward
> sentence at best and completely change the meaning at worst.

Quoting from the following link:
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adverb/

In accordance with the above, the following seem most accurate:

- He spoke optimistically to the people.
- He optimistically spoke to the people.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Thanks for including a reference. Your answer could be improved by rewording it so it answers the original question on whether to put the adverb before or after.